# What is the probability of your next choice that make your choices uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, statistics, random, monty-hall

Given an #n of balls. you are only allowed to pick between two balls at a time with a probability
$P_{i}=0.5$
with i being the number of the ball.

For example: you're presented with a black ball and a red ball.. so to be uniformly distributed the probability would be
$P_{black}=P_{red}=0.5$ so you pick the red ball and forget about the black ball.

but then you're introduced to a blue ball. what is the probability of picking the blue
$P_{picking}$ ball so that the set would be uni-formally distributed?
$P_{black}=P_{red}=P_{blue}=1/3$

after each pick you're given a new ball what is the $p_{picking}$ to make $p_{ball}=1/n$

How do you go about solving this?

Comment: Probabilities are between zero and one. Can you clearly restate your question?

Comment: $p_{picking}=0.5$ as the sample space was 2 balls.. but then a new item was introduced so what is the $p_{picking}=?$ of the new item to make it the sample uniformly distributed

Comment: the percentage sign was not visible so I changed it back to a fraction thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are picking in a sequential order either to pick the next ball or not with the main goal of making the distribution of result uniform which means that for all balls it's equally likely for all other balls to be selected.

so let's analyze the first three balls.

$P_{picking}=100\%$ for the first ball $P_{1st} = 100\%$

$p_{picking}=50\%$ for the second ball $P_{1st} = 50\% , P_{2nd}=50\%$

$P_{picking}= ??$ for the third ball, for this we have to consider

1. sequence of our actions $50\%$ to pick one of the previous balls and $X\%$ to pick the third ball
2. The number of ways the ball can be picked {(1st,third),(2nd,third)} $n_{ways} = 2$
3. our goal is to make $p_{3rd} = \frac{1}{3}$

$P_{3rd} = P_{picking,3rd} \times p_{picking,2nd} \times n_{ways}$

$P_{ball} = \frac{1}{n}$ **Target**

$ways = i-1$ where i equals the number of total balls

General form would be $P_{picking,new} = \frac{1}{i} / P_{picking,old} / (i-1)$

Credit: thanks for dsillman2000 for pointing out that the probability of the ball newly added ball equals to the sum of it's ways

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Math stack exchange!

Suppose we're dealing with $n$ balls, with ball $i$ having a probability of being chosen denoted $0\leq p_i\leq 1$. We also know that all of our probabilities need to sum up to $1$, so we have that

$$
p_1 + p_2 + p_3 +\cdots+p_n=1
$$

Because we want our probabilities to be evenly distributed, we want all of our probabilities to be equal, so

$$
p_1 = p_2 = p_3 =\cdots=p_n
$$

The solution to this problem (which you can verify rigorously by solving the system equations, if you want) is to set each probability $p_i = 1/n$. This works because

$$
\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \cdots \frac{1}{n} = n\cdot\frac{1}{n} = 1
$$
and
$$
p_1=\frac{1}{n}=p_2=\cdots=p_n
$$
So the case with $n=3$ balls means we have a probability of each ball being chosen at $p_i=1/3$.

Comment: Thank you, sorry if the question was not clear enough but n is a variable at first it's 2 then there is another ball which is introduced after picking the first ball. the goal is to make all $p_{i}=1/n$ so what would be the probability of $p_{picking}$ of the next ball. if it's 50% then wouldn't be $p_{blue}=0.5*0.5=0.25$ by rule of multiplication ?

Comment: Not exactly. Because there are two ways that blue could be picked; (1) first, we pick the red ball, then the blue ball (0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25), or (2) first, we pick the black ball, then the blue ball (0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25). We add these two probabilities together to get 0.5 in total. Sorry for not understanding your initial question correctly.

Comment: Don't worry about it, yeah ur right we could also think about it this way, when you introduce a new ball and your $p_{picking}=0.5$ that means that you divided the space into two parts one that has the new ball which will have a probability of 50% and the other space with holds the other 50% divided between the first two balls that means the new ball will have $p_{new}=.5$ and the old balls $p_{old,1}=0.25 , p_{old,2}=0.25$ I don't think this is the solution but this is my guess $p_{picking, i}= 1/i * p_{picking,i-1}$

Comment: Figured it out, Thanks for pointing the fact that the probability of new ball equal to the sum of the ways... the correct formula should be $P_{picking,new}=(1/i)/P_{picking,old}/(i-1)$ I'll write a detailed answer for it.